# Outer product of average and average of outer product in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, math

I have two 3d column vectors `B_mu` and `B_nu` that vary as a function of time:

```py
import numpy as np
N = 5 # 5 time-steps

B_mu = np.array(
      [[5, 5, 8],
       [4, 8, 7],
       [2, 3, 1],
       [5, 7, 8],
       [6, 2, 7]]
)
B_nu = np.array(
      [[3, 2, 9],
       [9, 8, 8],
       [4, 9, 9],
       [4, 9, 6],
       [1, 9, 1]]
)
```

For every index `i` in the first vector, and every index `j` in the second vector, I want to compute **the difference between the time-average of the product `< B_mu[i] B_nu[j] >`** and the **product of the time-averages <B_mu[i]> <B_nu[j]>**.

In other words, I want to construct the matrix `M` such that:

```
M[i,j] = 1/N sum(B_mu[i] * B_nu[j]) - 1/N**2 * sum(B_mu[i]) * sum(B_nu[j])
```

where the sums are taken over the time parameter.

Here is the equation:

[image: short equation]

And an explicit, expanded version:

[image: explicit equation]

How can I express this equation in python?

Comment: "And B_mu and B_nu are both sets of numbers. " << Are you sure? Sets of numbers? Not matrices?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! The question is interesting. This can probably done efficiently with module numpy. Not pandas. However, the question is a little bit confusing and hard to understand right now. I suggest trying to rewrite it in a more clear and concise way. (I notice that several people have already "downvoted" the question, presumably because they found it too confused).

Comment: <> indicate that the enclosed
quantity is averaged over some designated interval of time. That is expressed in summation form in Equation (2). Basically what I'm trying to do is finding covariance matrix of B_1 B_2 B_3 data columns.

Comment: "So basically, What I did was I created 3D array from 3 column values and assign indexes 1,2,3 respectively." <<< Please include an explicit example in your question. Something like `Bmu = [[3,5,7],[1,2,2],[1,1,1]]` and `Bnu = ...`. Explicit examples make it waaaaaay more easy for the people reading to understand what you're doing.

Comment: I have an excel file with 3 columns: Bx, By, and Bz (cartesian coordinates) with N number elements. 
I'm trying to find a covariance Matrix of it.  I actually did find the covariant matrix just by making data = np.array([Bx ,By, Bz])
and covariantMatrix =np.cov(data_mva,bias=True), and I got my answer. 
But I'm not sure whether it is correct or not. So I decided to do it manually by following above equation.

Comment: I have edited your question extensively. Hopefully I got what you meant. If you don't like my edit, you can roll it back. Or you can further edit.

Comment: Sure thanks for your edit and everything. In my case, B_mu and B_nu arrays have same values since I created them out of three values of Bx, By, Bz column elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulation of matrices is relatively easy with module numpy. Here we're looking for:

- averaging (or summing) over one dimension (time);
- taking the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of two column vectors.

We're going to use:

- [method `array.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html#numpy.ndarray.sum) with the optional `axis` parameter to sum over the time dimension;
- [function `outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html).

These two functions combine straightforwardly to compute the product of averages. The average of the products, on the other hand, is straightforward to compute with python builtins `sum` and `map`; I don't know how to do it in pure numpy.

```py
import numpy as np

def diff_avgprod_prodavg(B_mu, B_nu):
    N = B_mu.shape[0]
    avg_of_prod = 1/N * sum(map(np.outer, B_mu, B_nu)) # not pure numpy
    prod_of_avg = 1/(N*N) * np.outer(B_mu.sum(axis=0), B_nu.sum(axis=0))
    return avg_of_prod - prod_of_avg
```

Testing:

```py
B_mu = np.array(
      [[5, 5, 8],
       [4, 8, 7],
       [2, 3, 1],
       [5, 7, 8],
       [6, 2, 7]]
)
B_nu = np.array(
      [[3, 2, 9],
       [9, 8, 8],
       [4, 9, 9],
       [4, 9, 6],
       [1, 9, 1]]
)

print( diff_avgprod_prodavg(B_mu, B_nu) )
# [[-1.48 -0.76 -2.84]
#  [ 4.8  -0.6   3.  ]
#  [-0.04 -2.68 -2.52]]

print( diff_avgprod_prodavg(B_mu, B_mu) )
# [[1.84 0.   3.12]
#  [0.   5.2  2.8 ]
#  [3.12 2.8  6.96]]

print( diff_avgprod_prodavg(B_nu, B_nu) )
# [[ 6.96  0.72  4.28]
#  [ 0.72  7.44 -3.64]
#  [ 4.28 -3.64  9.04]]
```

Comment: Dear Stef, I have no words to express my dearest gratitude to you. 
It is just amazing that so many talented and smart people spend their valuable time helping others. Thank you very much.